# retrieve result of async function inside of another async function

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm facing this problem with async function

my_class.py

```
class cl:
    async def foo():
        return 

    async def bar(foo):
        #some code here
        return result
```

main.py

```
from my_class import cl
import asyncio

c = cl()
r = asyncio.run(c.foo)
x = cl.bar(r)
s = asyncio.run(x)
```

How can I retrieve the return of *foo()* to the function *bar()* because now I get this error :

```
ValueError: The future belongs to a different loop than the one specified as the loop argument
```

THANKS!!

Comment: This is currently toy-level so I don't know what you're trying to do at a larger scale, but you could put all the work with `cl` in method and have `asyncio.run` run the method itself. Right now you're running two separate `async` loops and trying to pass futures between them.

Comment: The why I used it separately is I try to load page(from playwright) first in my *foo()* method and I will use this page's frame in my *bar()* meth so I won't waste time to load it anymore inside my *bar()* meth

Answer (score 0):

Futures in Python imply that the result is available in the **future**, as the asynchronous function has not "finished" executing. I assume you will want to wait for `foo` to "finish" running in `bar` before using its value. This should do it:

```py
import asyncio


class cl:
    async def foo(self):
        return 

    async def bar(self):
        value = await self.foo()  # waits for foo, then gets its value
        #some code here
        return result


c = cl()
x = c.bar()
s = asyncio.run(x)
```

*Note: I changed some minor syntax so this code snippet can execute as-is*

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want the *foo()* method run separately to the *bar()*
What I try to do is ny my *foo()* I want to return a *page.goto* from playwright and I'll take the frame of this page in my *bar()* method so I could work with the frame of this page\
I have already try to run all of the task inside my *bar()* and it works correctly but it takes time for loading page that's why I need to load the page first before working in it

Comment: @nix20536 I would like to mention that there is no "true concurrency" in Python programs due to something called the Global Interpreter Lock, which makes sure the Python interpreter is only executing one set of code at any given time. The way `asyncio` works is not by running functions at the same time, but instead by running them back and forth, switching execution between async functions based on when they're free. Therefore, I'm not sure why you want *foo* to run separately from *bar*, if bar relies on the result from *foo* to continue processing.